# Python 3.3 pyqtgraph can't plot points

Tags: python-3.x, plot, pyqtgraph

Is it me, or is it impossible to plot points (scatterplot) in pyqtgraph using Python 3.3?

I have quite big data*, and find matplotlib way too slow, so I would like to give this a try:

1) `pyqtgraph.plot([1],[1])` shows nothing in the plot.

2) `pyqtgraph.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])`  shows a line connecting the dots

3) `pyqtgraph.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], pen=None)` as suggested by docs, errors**

4) `pyqtgraph.ScatterPlotItem()` does not exist.

I do not know what to try anymore... Did anyone get this working and would be willing to share code?

---

*  I am aware of the irony with the data I present, forgive me.

** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'.

*** Perhaps unrelated, but I also can't get the examples to run (Ubuntu 13.04).

Comment: you should change the tags so you get the library you are actually using, not the one you aren't using

Comment: @tcaswell "Point" taken.

Comment: You should post to the pyqtgraph mailing list about trouble running the examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct ways to create a scatter plot are either by specifying the symbol properties when plotting (symbol, symbolPen, symbolBrush, symbolSize; see the [PlotDataItem API](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotDataItem.__init__)):

```
pg.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], pen=None, symbol='o')
```

Or by directly creating a ScatterPlotItem, which seems to exist on my end:

```
>>> import pyqtgraph as pg
>>> pg.ScatterPlotItem
<class 'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ScatterPlotItem.ScatterPlotItem'>
```

See `examples/ScatterPlot.py` on how to use the latter method.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643629/luke).
I was able to find a solution with the help of your reply.

```
x = np.float64(10.5)
y = np.float64(6.4)
x_gap = (0.001 * x) / 100.0
y_gap = (0.001 * y) / 100.0
x_list = [(x - gap_q), x, (x + gap_q), x]
y_list = [(y), (y + y_gap), y, (y - y_gap)]
pg.plot(x_list, y_list,
              pen=None,
              name="BEP",
              symbol='o',
              symbolPen=pg.mkPen(color=(0, 0, 255), width=0),                                      
              symbolBrush=pg.mkBrush(0, 0, 255, 255),
              symbolSize=7)
```